# Data bound to table, retrieve multiple row data using checkboxes?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm totally new to knockout and I'm trying to expand upon some binding data examples.

Below shows objects binded to a table:

```
<table> 
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Games">
        <tr>
            <!--<td style="width:auto;">
                <input name="GameSelect" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedGames" />
            </td>-->
            <td data-bind="text:Name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Group"></td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.GameGroups, optionsText: 'GameGroupName', optionsValue: 'GameGroupId', value: $parent.filter"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bind="click: $parent.makeChanges">Change »</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!--<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-bind="click:makeChangesAll">Change All</button>-->
```

Clicking change will get the object containing the data for that row and use it with the makechanges function:

```
        self.makeChanges = function (data) {
        ...
        }
```

I'm trying to add a checkbox to each table row and an additional button to get all the selected objects at once, I just can't get it to work. Some of my attempts are in the commented out code. Can anyone please tell me how to go from the one data object per row with the makeChanges functions to getting multiple for every checkbox selected with a makeChangesAll function?

Comment: It looks like `selectedGames` has the objects you want. I think you may need to show more code. How about setting up a fiddle?

Comment: i'll give that a go now

Answer (score 1):

It works pretty much the way you wrote it. Just use `selectedGames()` in the click handler.

```js
function game(name, group) {
  return {
    Name: name,
    Group: group
  };
}

var vm = (function() {
  var result = {
    selectedGames: ko.observableArray(),
    Games: ko.observableArray([
      game('one', 'group1'),
      game('two', 'group1'),
      game('three', 'group2'),
      game('four', 'group2')
    ]),
    makeChangesAll: function() {
      console.debug("Selected Games:", result.selectedGames());
    }
  };

  return result;
}());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Games">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:auto;">
        <input name="GameSelect" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedGames" />
      </td>
      <td data-bind="text:Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Group"></td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.GameGroups, optionsText: 'GameGroupName', optionsValue: 'GameGroupId', value: $parent.filter"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" data-bind="click:makeChangesAll">Change All</button>
```

Comment: Nice; Didn't know *"Special consideration is given if your parameter resolves to an **array**. In this case, KO will set the element to be checked if the value matches an item in the array, and unchecked if it is not contained in the array."* -http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html However, this does not work without the `value` binding?

Comment: @Tyblitz All checkboxes with the same value would be tied together, so having unique `value` bindings is usually what you want.